# Sending and recieving data over wifi connection in android programatically

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I am trying to make a app that communicates with a hotspot in my pc. I am being able to connect to the hotspot but i am not being able to figure out how to send and recieve data in android. This is my code as of now in my app.

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
// setup a wifi configuration
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
wc.SSID = "\"pigo\"";
wc.preSharedKey = "\"12345678\"";
wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
wc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
wc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
// connect to and enable the connection
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
stepinfo.setText("Initiating Connection . . .");
```

I have looked at other similar questions but nothing seems to be working with my app.

Comment: Hotspot in a pc? Please explain how one makes a hotspot in a pc?

Comment: Your code does something with wifi manager. Ok. But to what exactly do you want to send data?

Comment: @greenapps using cmd in admin mode
 step1 ) netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=pigo key=12345678 

step2 ) netsh wlan start hostednetwork

Comment: Sorry i do not understand that.

Answer (score 0):

By doing what you are doing above you can only connect to the hotspot of the computer (Windows PC - given you are using netsh wlan). This will allow you to connect to your PC and at max share its internet. But to enable communication between your computer and your phone, you need to build an app over this layer.

What this app will do is. It will listen on specific port(s) on your PC and your mobile. So when the connection through hotspot is established you will need to have a `Socket` and do `Socket.connect(new InetAddress(IP, PORT))`. Lets say your computer listens on `PORT_0`, then your mobile needs to do  `Socket.connect(new InetAddress(IP_COMPUTER, PORT_0))`.

This way you now have a socket which can be used for communication between your PC and your mobile.